# 2011 Nissan Titan runs poorly when outside temperature goes up

Tags: troubleshooting, nissan, overheating, titan

My thermostat gasket failed and the engine overheated to the point of knocking and dying. I replaced the thermostat and it ran normally, however when the outside temperature goes over 90º F it starts to lose power going up hill or passing, in cooler temperatures all is normal. The engine feels like it's not getting enough gas, I live in the foothills so on hot days, I need to shift into 3rd to get up the hills.

Any advice would be great, the check engine light goes on, then a day later its off again. How can I track down what is happening – and hopefully get it fixed.

Comment: Have you had the codes read? The computer will normally store the codes, even if the CEL goes off. Post up if you have them.

Comment: When you get the codes read (they will probably shed a lot of light on the problem) please add them to the question.